# UI lags during heavy computation operation in Flutter even with async

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, encryption, cryptography

I'm working on a password manager application in Flutter, while running this code snippet for my hashing function:

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as EncryptLib;
import 'package:pinenacl/key_derivation.dart' as HashLib;

Map<String, String> hash(String masterPass) {
  final salt = EncryptLib.IV.fromSecureRandom(16);

  final hashedMasterPass = HashLib.PBKDF2
      .hmac_sha512(utf8.encode(masterPass), salt.bytes, 100100, 32);

  return {
    "hashedMasterPass": base64.encode(hashedMasterPass),
    "salt": salt.base64,
  };
}
```

When I call this function from a button such as:

```
TextButton(
  child: Text("Hash Password"),
  onPressed: () {
    print(hash("ThisIsTheMasterPassword"));
})
```

The animation for the button press completely halts and so does the rest of the UI, I read up a bit about Futures and async and came up with the following, expecting the UI to not freeze:

```
Future<Map<String, String>> hash(String masterPass) async {
  final salt = EncryptLib.IV.fromSecureRandom(16);

  final hashedMasterPass = HashLib.PBKDF2
      .hmac_sha512(utf8.encode(masterPass), salt.bytes, 100100, 32);

  return {
    "hashedMasterPass": base64.encode(hashedMasterPass),
    "salt": salt.base64,
  };
}
```

and...

```
TextButton(
  child: Text("Hash Password"),
  onPressed: () {
    hash("ThisIsTheMasterPassword").then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
})
```

Same results, the UI is still freezing like before, is there any way I can make this particular code not freeze the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
TextButton(
  child: Text("Hash Password"),
  onPressed: () {
    hash("ThisIsTheMasterPassword").then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
})
```

use this

```
TextButton(
      child: Text("Hash Password"),
      onPressed: () async{
        hash("ThisIsTheMasterPassword").then((value) {
          print(value);
        });
    })
```

or

```
TextButton(
      child: Text("Hash Password"),
      onPressed: ()async {
       var value=await hash("ThisIsTheMasterPassword");
print(value);

    })
```

You can use `isolate` to calculate of sth out of the main thread. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrFTt1NZed8

```
compute(hash, "ThisIsTheMasterPassword");
```

Further reading https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: Thank you, `insolate` was exactly what I was looking for!